# Diagonal of Green's Function

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, elliptic-pde, random-walks, green-function

I am looking to numerically calulate the diagonal of Green's function. I am interested in Green's functions of elliptic PDEs and in those that arise from stochastic processes (discrete and continuous). I am aware of the connection - that is why I am interested in whatever I can find. Most literature I found is concerned with showing the diagonal is not regular in some sense and with bounds on it.

Let $G$ be the Green's function of $(-\Delta + \kappa)^2$ ($\kappa$ a constant killing rate) on $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d, d \leq 3$. This operator needs two boundary conditions on $\Omega$. Take these conditions to be any of the standard three homogeneous boundary conditions taken with each application of the operator.

Is there a PDE that $G(x,x)$ satisfies? The probabilistic interpretation of the of Green's function is the expected number of visits to the start point (at least for random walks on graphs). I expect the diagonal to be harmonic if $k=0$. Is that true? Reasonable?

Here's what I've tried:
For $d=1$, taking $y(x) = x$ and differentiating $\frac{d^2 G(x,y(x))}{dx^2}$, 
I get a term $\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x \partial y}|_{y=x}$ which I don't know what to do with. Using Mercer's theorem (assuming eigenfunctions are real, at least for now):

$$
G(x,y) = \sum_n \lambda_{n} \Psi_{n}(x) \Psi_n(y)  
$$

I get

$$
\frac{d^2 G(x,x)}{dx^2} = \sum_n \lambda_{n} \frac{d^2 \Psi_n^2(x)}{dx^2}\\
%
%  
=2\sum_n \lambda_{n} \bigg (\Psi_n''(x)\Psi_n(x) +  [\Psi_n'(x)]^2 \bigg )\\
%
%  
=2\frac{\partial ^2 G(x,y(x))}{\partial x^2} + \sum_n \lambda_{n} [\Psi_n'(x)]^2\\
$$

which is (not surprisingly) pretty much the same problem.
I considered taking an eigenvalue expansion of $(-\Delta + \kappa)^{-1}$
but I'm hoping for a better approach.

References I know:
The authors of [Diagonals of Green's functions and applications](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0362546X14003617) consider Green's functions for Sturm-Liouville operators that look similar to the operator I described above. They consider only one dimension - time. I don't know if this can be genralized to more than one spatial dimension. They do present a differential equation for the diagonal of the corresponding Green's function. However, their operator has non-homogeneous Dirichlet BC. They say their derivation was originally proposed in [Semilinear Elliptic Equations Involving Critical Sobolev Exponents](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/322/art%253A10.1007%252FBF00256931.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2FBF00256931&token2=exp=1464041325~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F322%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252FBF00256931.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252FBF00256931*~hmac=5d2ebc35360f4aa626ba15a2b82c2547427099d8bbce1e20fe38f740515f526e) but I couldn't find any reference to diagonals in the latter.

Comment: Consider an (elliptic) differential operator $D(\partial)$ of degree $k$ with constant coefficients on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g., a power of the Laplacian). Its Green function $G(x,y)=g(x-y)$ is the Fourier transform of $1/D(ip)$, interpreted as a distribution. Roughly speaking, for large $|p|$, it will behave like $|p|^{-k}$, which translates to $g(x) \sim |x|^{n-k}$ for small $|x|$, which is generic behavior even on bounded domains and with non-constant coefficients. In other words, unless $k>n$, you should expect $G(x,x)=g(0)=\infty$.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine thanks, you are absolutely right. I should have phrased my question better, since I am specifically interested in cases where $k > n$. I will change my question accordingly.